# cordova ratchet popover selecting item from popover then hitting "menu" button makes whole screen go white

Tags: jquery, cordova, ratchet

I'm building a cordova app using ratchet.css and ratchet.js, I've set up a menu icon with the code to display the popover with menu items in it.  right now I have 2 items but only 1 show at a time.  login and logout.  when you first open the app, everything is good, you click the menu button (and if you are logged in it will show logout and if logged out it will show login.) you select the logout item and it will complete the task of logging out but when you hit the menu icon again to show the popover the entire page goes white and you can no longer do anything.  the same thing happens after you login, if you hit the button again, the popover will show up but then the whole page goes white and you can do nothing.

```
...
<a href="#myPopover">
   <div class="pull-right menu"><span class="icon icon-bars"></span></div>
</a>

<div id="myPopover" class="popover">
    <ul class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell logout" {{hide}} onclick="logout(event)">Logout</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell login" {{show}} onclick="window.location='#login'">Login</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
...
```

logout function

```
loggedin = false;
alert('logged out successfully');
window.location="#";
```

login function

```
loggedin = true;
window.location = '#';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use ratchet.js there are quite a few people out there that say not to, and now I agree.  just doesn't work very well.  ratchet.css seems to be fine though.  anyway, I deleted ratchet.js and used this instead for the popover action

```
$('#myPopover').toggleClass('visible').toggle()
```

now it works great on the desktop and the mobile